# my canvas does not draw in jsfiddle

Tags: canvas, jsfiddle

I would like a code review of my little canvas project so I thought I'd make it available on jsfiddle but for some reason my canvas does not draw on jsfiddle. It works fine locally on my computer. Please advise

https://jsfiddle.net/wastelandtime/su2q5pp9/1/

HTML:

```
    <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <button onclick="resetCanvas()">Reset</button>
    <button onclick="isSym(arr)">Check</button>
    <script>
          // Pageload
          window.addEventListener("load", function load(event) {

            //Call only the functions you want to use on this page here
            //and pass the elements as parameters if you use abstract functions
            arr = genArray(6);
            canvasCreate(300, 300);
            drawGrid(arr);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseClick, false);

          });
          </script>
    </body>
```

script.js

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasCreate = function(w, h) {
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
};

function resetCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    arr = genArray(6);
    drawGrid(arr);
}

// Generate a 6x6 array of 0s or 1s
function genArray(aSize) {
    var a = [];
    var count = 0
    for (var i=0;i<aSize;i++) {
        a[i] = [];
        for (var j=0;j<aSize;j++) {
            a[i][j] = (count < 10) ? Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) : 0;
            count = (a[i][j]== 1) ? count+=1 : count;

        }
    }
    return a;
}

function drawGrid(arr) {
    var n = 6;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#555';
            if (arr[i][j] === 1) {
                ctx.fillStyle = '#3399ff';
                ctx.fillRect(i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);
            } else {
                ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
                ctx.fillRect(i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);
            }
            ctx.rect(i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

    }
    var hw = canvas.width / 2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
    ctx.moveTo(hw, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(hw, canvas.height);
    ctx.stroke();
}

// Get mouse position within canvas
function mouseClick(e) {
    var mouseX, mouseY;

    if(e.offsetX) {
        mouseX = e.offsetX;
        mouseY = e.offsetY;
    }
    else if(e.layerX) {
        mouseX = e.layerX;
        mouseY = e.layerY;
    }
    var gridX = Math.floor(mouseX / 50);
    var gridY = Math.floor(mouseY / 50);

    var xy = arr[gridX][gridY];
    if (xy == 0) {
        arr[gridX][gridY] = 1;
    }
    else if (xy == 1) {
        arr[gridX][gridY] = 0;
    }

    drawGrid(arr);
}


function isSym(arr) {
    var diff = 5;
    var tot = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
        var l = arr[i].join("");
        var r = arr[i + diff].join("");
        var comp = (l == r) ? 1 : 0;
        diff -= 2;
        tot += comp;
    }
    var isIt = (tot != 3) ? "wrong" : "right";
    alert("You are " + isIt + "!!!");
}
```

**Edit**: Having checked the console errors in jsfiddle, as recommended below, I found the following:
genArray is not defined (called from HTML file). There is a reason I want to call it from html, not script.js but this is for the code review question, not now. So the question is how can I make the JavaScript part in jsfiddle load first before the injected script that is embedded in html?

Comment: Check the console errors on the jsfiddle page, maybe that helps.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know / didn't think you could use the error console in fiddle. Silly me.

Comment: I've updated me question at the end